# How to compare text from two labels in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I make a string split on two labels. label1 contain firstPart of string and label2 contain secondPart of string. Now i want to compare the text from two labels to make full string and show an alert of success when press on a button.See in this image blue label and gray label make full string "window"   [words labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1J8f.jpg)
 Here is my logic i perform in button press action but it always gives alert of try again,can any one please tell me where is my mistake in code.

get the text from file and store in an array and set label text.

```
label1.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:i]; and        [label2.text = arr2 objectAtIndex:i];
```

in  button press method

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{

NSMutableArray *checkarry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<arr2.count;i++){

    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i],[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]];
    [checkarry addObject:str];

}


NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:arrayOfStringBeforeSpiliting];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:checkarry];


if([set1 isEqualToSet:set2]){




    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Congarats" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Try Again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to diagnose your issue? Have you run under the debugger, stepped through the methods and examined the values of your variables? Tried inserting `NSLog` calls at strategic points? Etc. Your code sample is both a bit long, in that it contains stuff probably irrelevant to the problem; and a bit short, in that it omits stuff which probably is relevant, e.g. where is `arr2` defined and given a value? If after trying to isolate the issue you are still stuck edit your question to show what you've tried, improve the code sample, and someone will probably be able to help. HTH

Comment: @CRD i debug it with breakpoints and every thing is fine but it still show error alert and my arr2 is the text in array which i put on my label2

Comment: @CRD i updated my question i hope you understand now

Comment: "every thing is fine but it still show error alert" - that reads like you are saying the debugger shows that `set1` and `set2` have the same elements but then `isEqualToSet` returns false. I guess you don't mean that. Trace the values of all your arrays and sets before/after splitting/joining, at what point do you see something you don't expect? Examine that code more closely. You should find your error, but if you don't and end up stuck come back to SO with the code fragment with the error, give the input values, the output values, and why the latter isn't what you expect, etc. HTH